# Install older removed brew formula version

Tags: homebrew

While brew has an accessible simple versioning mechanism, it's restricted to versions *[used by a large number of people](https://docs.brew.sh/Versions.html)*. So for popular versions, it's easy:

```bsh
brew search node # gives node@6, node@8, node@10
brew search postgresql #gives postgresql@9.4, postgresql@9.5, postgresql@9.6, postgresql@10
brew search python # gives python@2
```

And I can install one for instance with `brew install python@2`.

But for less popular versions which got removed, let's say `git@2.20.1`, then it's not obvious how to install them:

> $ `brew install git@2.20.1`
>   Error: No available formula with the name "git@2.20.1"
>   ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
>   Error: No previously deleted formula found.
>   ==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
>   Error: No similarly named formulae found.
>   ==> Searching taps...
>   ==> Searching taps on GitHub...
>   Error: No formulae found in taps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution based on Versions.html doc

To install a removed brew formula version, we can follow the suggestion from https://docs.brew.sh/Versions.html:

1. We create an empty repo on our GitHub account: https://github.com/Coeur/homebrew-repo
2. We add an empty commit to it (`git commit --allow-empty -m "first commit"`), otherwise brew may not find HEAD.
3. We extract the old formula with `brew extract git Coeur/repo --version=2.20.1`
4. We install this old formula with `brew install coeur/repo/git@2.20.1`

(note: uninstall command will be `brew uninstall git@2.20.1`)
More doc at https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap

---

#### Solution based on manual search

1. Find the repository of the formula with `brew info git`. It should tell us it's https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/git.rb
2. From that page, click the *History* button on the right to get to https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master/Formula/git.rb
3. Choose a commit diff with your relevant version, for instance https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/67903b677219559ac72b3fb45932d43426e157f0#diff-3e84bae646d908b93e043833873d316d for 2.20.1
4. Click *View file* to get to the full file at this version: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/67903b677219559ac72b3fb45932d43426e157f0/Formula/git.rb
5. Click *Raw* to get to the raw file at this version: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/67903b677219559ac72b3fb45932d43426e157f0/Formula/git.rb
6. We install this formula with `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/67903b677219559ac72b3fb45932d43426e157f0/Formula/git.rb`

(note: uninstall command will be `brew uninstall git`)

Comment: Hi, this is not working for me as it gives the following error: `Error: Non-checksummed download of node%4010 formula file from an arbitrary URL is unsupported! brew extract or brew create and brew tap-new to create a formula file in a tap on GitHub instead.`